# How to get data 30 days data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to get 30 days records from the table.

```
df['Form Modified Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Form Modified Date'].astype(str), format='%Y/%m/%d')
#print (df)
timenow = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) - 30 days

nya= df[(df['Form Modified Date'] == (timenow))]
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a few options:

1. `df.loc`

```
dayfrom = pd.to_datetime('1/23/2020')

#set index from column Date
df = df.set_index('Date')
df= df.sort_index()

#last 30 days of date lastday
df = df.loc[dayfrom - pd.Timedelta(days=30):dayfrom].reset_index()
```

2. `DataFrame.last_valid_index()`

```
df[df.last_valid_index()-pandas.DateOffset(30, 'D'):]
```